# Are there any Bayeux clients in Python?

Tags: python, cometd, bayeux

I need to connect to a Bayeux server form a wxPython APP.

I would appreciate any hint about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I've found an example client here:

http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/cometd-twisted/