# Are there any Bayeux clients in Python to subscribe to salesforce push-topic (streaming API)

Tags: python, machine-learning, cometd, bayeux

I want to get the [push-topic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/pushtopic.htm), [salesforce streaming api](https://appirio.com/tech-blog/the-salesforce-streaming-api-with-example) data to frontend python client. I have seen few articles but none of them deals with python frontend. Most on Node.js. It would be really helpful if someone can point on how to subscribe to streaming API data from salesforce in python. I want to run few machine learning algorithms to the data received and write back the result to salesforce.

The link in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809202/are-there-any-bayeux-clients-in-python) SO post does not work.

Comment: I can confirm that the linked `cometd-twisted` module is not working and has been removed from the CometD project (lack of interest). I am not aware of any CometD python client, sorry.

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615641/connect-cometd-client-with-kafka-producer