# Connect CometD client with Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, cometd

Is it possible to connect cometD client with Kafka producer? Any suggestions?

Currently I am having a CometD client in python which is extracting data real time from a Salesforce object.

Now I want to push that data into Kafka producer. Is it possible to do that? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

By using https://github.com/dkmadigan/python-bayeux-client to extract the events from Salesforce, I was able to push into the Kafka broker.

Comment: But apparently it does not have replay option. Hence inclined towards using it in Java